# regular expression extract fully qualified decimals

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to write a pattern for `preg_match_all` in regex that will give me a list of fully qualified decimals in a string.

i.e. `1.2`, `0.20`, `.30` should be included... `3.` should not.

Comment: Please include the code that you have tried - have a read of [*How to Ask a Good Question*](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try this:

```
$str = "i.e. 1.2, 0.20, .30 should be included... 3. should not.";

$matches = array();

preg_match_all('/([0-9]*\.[0-9]+)/', $str, $matches);

var_dump($matches);
```

And result is:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(3) "1.2"
    [1]=>
    string(4) "0.20"
    [2]=>
    string(3) ".30"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(3) "1.2"
    [1]=>
    string(4) "0.20"
    [2]=>
    string(3) ".30"
  }
}
```